# JSON object name is undefined, how to access the parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am sending a request to a web server and get the below response:

Using `JSON.stringify` it looks as follows:

```
undefined{\"access_token\":\"Rhazjww5 ...QUiTMVc\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\":86399,\".issue
d\":\"Thu, 16 Aug 2018 13:50:28 GMT\",\".expires\":\"Fri, 17 Aug 2018 13:50:28 G
MT\"}"
```

I need the access_token part of the object, but do not know how to access it.
I tried `var.access_token` and `var['access_token']`, where `var` is the variable I stored the object.

How can I access the data in the object?

Thank you

Comment: `undefined{\"access_token\":` That looks pretty broken. Fix the backend first.

Comment: show your object data or code...

Comment: A string starting with `undefined` like that is not valid JSON. It's hard to see how this came from `JSON.stringify`. And why are you calling `stringily` on the response? Have you tried `var.access_token` on the data returned from the server *without* stringify?

Comment: I cannot fix the backend as it is not my server. I am calling stringify to inspect why I didn't get the desired result when using var.access_token.

Comment: @jallmer, given json data is not valid,  you can here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't stringify already stringified data, use JSON.parse for parse string to js object

```
const obj = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(obj['access_token']);
```

Comment: This leads to the following error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0' since the object starts as undefined {..}.

Comment: need to fix response from the back-end, or you can delete undefined from your text

Comment: I first parsed the result as a string. Deleting 'undefined' from the string and then using JSON.parse was a better solution.